# How can I implement openllet reasoner to my stain/jena-fuseki Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jena, inference, fuseki

I've had some issues at implementing built-in jena-fuseki reasoner, I could make it work but it would not prevent me from adding incorrect triples. So I wanted to add Openllet reasoner to my jena-fuseki server.

But I can't figure how to add openllet jar to my Docker image and make it work, I've run into many java dependances issues.
To add context, my **docker-compose** looks like that :

```yaml
  jena-fuseki-server:
    hostname: jena-fuseki

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    environment:
      - ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - FUSEKI_DATASET_1=ds
```

my **server.Dockerfile** looks like that, what I'm doing is copying my config/ontologies files to my image aswell as my openllet jar, I'm then trying to execute it which produce this issue:
`jena-fuseki-server_1  | /bin/sh: 1: [java,: not found`

```sh
FROM stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0

#This is made to stop Issue with JVM locks

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends procps

RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/ontologies/
RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/configuration/
RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/inference/

RUN mkdir -p /fuseki
WORKDIR /fuseki


COPY server/openllet inference
COPY server/configuration configuration
COPY server/test ontologies

CMD ["java", "-jar", inference/openllet-distribution-2.6.5-sources.jar]
```

My **configuration file** call is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764065/how-to-use-openllet-owl2-reasoner-or-any-other-with-jena-tdb) without the tdb because i'm only testing for now, she looks like this and worked for OWLMini + Generic

```sh
@prefix tdb:   <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .

<#service1> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
    fuseki:name                       "ds" ;       # http://host:port/ds
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "sparql" ;   # SPARQL query service
    fuseki:serviceQuery               "query" ;    # SPARQL query service (alt name)
    fuseki:serviceUpdate              "update" ;   # SPARQL update service
    fuseki:serviceUpload              "upload" ;   # Non-SPARQL upload service
    fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;     # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read and write)
    # A separate read-only graph store endpoint:
    fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore      "get" ;      # SPARQL Graph store protocol (read only)
    fuseki:dataset                   <#dataset> ;
    .

<#dataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph <#modelInf> ;
    .


<#modelInf> rdf:type ja:InfModel ;
    ja:content [ja:externalContent <file:/fuseki/ontologies/server_famille.ttl> ; ] ;
    ja:reasoner   [
        ja:reasonerClass    "openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory" ; ]
  .
```

I'm using the familly ontology for testing purposes,

> What else have you tried ?

I've been trying things described in the links bellow, most of them has been resolved and lead me to other issues which made me have to think otherwise :

- [fuseki-how-to-add-pellet-reasoner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313972/fuseki-how-to-add-pellet-reasoner)
- Adding jar to jena home (/jena-fuseki) in docker [permissions-jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/permissions/example.html)
- [cant-get-openllet-running-on-fuseki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077823/cant-get-openllet-running-on-fuseki)
- Tried to install open jdk in docker but couldn't run apt-get jdk 8

I also run a lot into this issue

> ERROR Exception in initialization: the class 'openllet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory' required by the object 34064d96e625bd1f4718dc614ac47d38 [ja:reasoner of file:///fuseki/configuration/db_tdb.ttl#modelInf] could not be loaded

People usually use Openllet for maven or coupled with a Java project but i'm only using config file and a Backend API to make calls, everything is configured in what I've shown you.
Since I'm still new to docker and jena-fuseki, it may be a conceptual issue with what I am trying to do, so if you have any idea about where should I seek more information, I will be very thankfull.

Comment: If you're using the JSON-array form of `CMD`, every word needs to be in double-quotes.  Since what you have isn't a valid JSON array, Docker falls back to processing it with a shell, leading to the `[java` error.  Does double-quoting the jar file name in the `CMD` resolve your problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze it resolve one of my issues but then I am getting ```no main manifest attribute``` I find out that ```openllet-distribution-2.6.5-sources``` has an empty manifest file but not ```original-openllet-distribution-2.6.5.jar``` and still run the same issue, since it's an other topic, I may try to resolve this issue myself and come back later.
Thanks for your explaination, it helped me understand how CMD worked =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything from google but I find this on github : [The answer](https://github.com/giulianodelagala/CURIOCITY/blob/8c7329764f027275c33ef4f623cdbcdb62b6d143/Manuals/PelletReasonerJena.md)

I followed his step by downloading the jar into my server/openllet and extracted the file so I could copy them in the new extra folder with all dependencies

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM stain/jena-fuseki:4.0.0

#This is made to stop Issue with JVM locks

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends procps

RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/ontologies/
RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/configuration/
RUN mkdir -p /fuseki/extra/

RUN mkdir -p /fuseki
WORKDIR /fuseki

COPY server/openllet/jar_files extra
COPY server/configuration configuration
COPY server/test ontologies
```

I could still verify SWRL inference. without having to use the built in GenericRuleReasoner + OWLMiniReasoner